# Strange situation in making backup on an external disk

Tags: macos, external-disk

[image]

As the screenshot above shows, tonight, while trying to make a backup of the files on my Mac OS X, Version 10.7.5, Processor 2.4GHz Intel core i5, Memory 4 GB 1333 MHz DDR3 laptop computer, I got this strange message:

> The item "Documents.zip" can't be copied because it is too large for the volume's format

Now, the file in question, as the home window shows, is 32.68GB, and, as shown in the window just behind it, the hard disk I'm trying to copy it onto has 191.58GB available, so it should fit. So what is the reason of this complaint? Is this linked to apple (Mac) or is it the Hard Disk, which is a LACIE disk? How can I overcome this problem, if possible, or raise the "too large for the format" threshold to at least 8GB, from the ~4GB it currently sits at?

And have I chosen the appropriate SX for this, and if not, which SE would be more fit?

Comment: You will gain speed in the transfer, and reduce errors, by using the Terminal command `cp` for huge file counts: one copy window shows you copying 280k files! Doing this with such large numbers of files using the Finder adds substantially to processor overhead. The `cp` command just moves data, it doesn't examine the resource info of every file as Finder does.

Comment: But Terminal doesn't show estimates of time remaining, and I prefer to have an idea of how long it will take to copy things...

Comment: Those estimates can be skewed when transferring thousands (or in your case, hundreds of thousands) of files because Finder can only calculate on the fly - it doesn't look ahead. A mix of large and small files can really throw off the calculations. If you test with a folder of a few large files totaling 10GB, and then with a folder of thousands of small files totaling 10GB, you'll see the difference. In any case, the whole process is much faster using Terminal, no matter what the file sizes. YMMV.

Comment: Yeah I know those estimates are often wrong, but at leat it gives an upper bound. I don't recall a copy ever taking longer. Anyway, what does YMMV stand for?

Comment: "Your Milage May Vary"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing that volume's format is FAT32 and you're trying to copy file bigger than 4GB. That's FAT32 limit. [Check this](https://www.google.com.au/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=fat32%20file%20size%20limit) for a reference.

**As the first point of investigation, check what's the format of your partition. If it's FAT then that's the reason. Change it to exFAT, NTFS or native OSX.**

So available free space has nothing to do here and can be misleading.

Comment: But to change the format I must reformat it and erase the disk entirely... right?

Comment: Anyways, it is `MS-DOS (FAT)`, according to Disk Utility.